# ServiceBus unable to provide a security token

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

For a few days we have had a problem with our service bus in Azure. None of our serviceBuses (40 pcs) are responding and when restarted they can't connect and respond with

*[System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException] = {"The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://XYZ-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: 'The request was aborted: The request was canceled.'."}*

All sertificates, secrets and keys have been checked and found correct.

```
var tcpBinding = new NetTcpRelayBinding
{
    ConnectionMode = (TcpRelayConnectionMode)int.Parse("1"), //TcpRelayConnectionMode.Hybrid =1,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.Parse("20000000"),
    MaxBufferSize = int.Parse("20000000"),
    MaxBufferPoolSize = int.Parse("20000000"),
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
    {
        MaxDepth = int.Parse("32"),
        MaxArrayLength = int.Parse("20000000"),
        MaxStringContentLength = int.Parse("20000000"),
    },
};
tcpBinding.Security.Mode = (EndToEndSecurityMode)int.Parse("0"); //EndToEndSecurityMode.None =0

//if you change how the license is used you have to change it in the worker role too.
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.Parse("200");
_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IMessage),
    tcpBinding,
    new Uri("sb://XYZ.servicebus.windows.net/xyzabc") 
    ).Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior { TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("owner", "myFantasticSecret") });
_serviceHost.Open();
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

We have added 11 new service busses lately and restarted everything we can think of.

**Update:**

added timeouts to the tcp binding.

```
OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,2,0), 
CloseTimeout =  new TimeSpan(0,0,2,0),
SendTimeout =  new TimeSpan(0,0,2,0),
ReceiveTimeout =  new TimeSpan(0,0,2,0),
```

And still it throws a timeout after 20 seconds.